# Quotient of normalizer of Sylow subgroup of profinite group

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, profinite-groups

In this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257803027_The_hypercenter_of_a_profinite_group) about the hypercenter of a profinite group, in the proof of the first theorem the author states that if $G$ is a profinite group, $M$ is an open normal subgroup of $G$ and $S$ is a Sylow subgroup of $G$ (which implies that $MS/M$ is a Sylow subgroup of $G/M$), then we have
$$N_{G/M}\left(MS/M\right) = M\left(N_G\left(S\right)\right)/M.$$
It is easy to prove that $N_{G/M}\left(MS/M\right) = M\left(N_G\left(MS\right)\right)/M \geq M\left(N_G\left(S\right)\right)/M$ for any abstract group $G$, any $S \leq G$ and any $M \unlhd G$; but then I can't figure out the other inclusion.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It follows from the conjugacy part of Sylow's theorem. If $g \in N_G(MS)$, then $S^g \le MS$ and then $S^g$ is conjugate to $S$ in $MS$, so you get $g \in MN_G(S)$.

Comment: Right. Many thanks!